# C++ open multiple ofstreams in a loop

Tags: c++, ofstream

I need to open undefined number of files with ofstream to write in. the file names should have a format of plot1.xpm, plot2.xpm, plot3.xpm,... .
The program looks like this:
I don't know what should I place in stars.

```
for(m = 0; m < spf; m++){
    //some calculations on arr[]
    ofstream output(???);
    for(x = 0; x < n; x++){
        for(y = 0; y < n; y++){
            if (arr[x*n + y] == 0)
                output<<0;
            else output<<1;
        }
        output<<'\n';
        output.close();
    }
```

Comment: You are asking how to turn a number into a string?!

Comment: Any way to make this work would be fine. I haven't worked with strings ever.

Comment: `std::ofstream output("plot" + std::to_string(m) + ".xpm")` should work there. requires C++11 and above though.

Comment: If you never have worked with strings, then I recommend you [find a good beginners book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) to read.

Comment: If you close the output stream in the first loop round, your loop is a bit pointless, non?

Comment: Kerrek: This piece of code is inside another do_while loop itself with changing m.

Comment: @AlirezaHashemi: The first iteration in `x` closes the stream. I think @KerrekSB suspects that `output.close()` should be in the `m` loop, not inside the `x` loop.

Comment: @Pixelchemist , KerrekSB You are right. My mistake. taken care of. Thanks you all.

Comment: You should break your problem down to its most basic, then perform some research on that basic element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`to_string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string):

```
std::string filename = "plot" + std::to_string(m) + ".xpm";
std::ofstream output(filename.c_str());
```

If the pattern is more complex you can also use [`std::stringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream):

```
std::stringstream filename_stream;
// use "operator<<" on stream to plug in parts of the file name
filename_stream << "plot" << m << ".xpm";
std::string filename = filename_stream.str();
std::ofstream output(filename.c_str());
```